# Django: how to count posts related to a category in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a model class `Category` and also a model class `Course`. i want to count all the courses that are related to a model e.g: **Web Devlopment - 26 Courses** i dont know how to go about this since the this are two diffrent models.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    course_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: You just need to apply filter on Course class with course category title = Web Development. And then just take the length of returned objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to set the `related_name` attribute in the `course_category` field.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    ...
    course_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, realted_name="courses" on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
```

Next, you can use this name to aggregate the query as the following.

```
from django.db.models import Count
cateogries = Category.objects.annotate(number_of_courses = Count("courses")).all()
```

Then, each of the `categories` will have the `number_of_courses` field that indicates the number of courses.

Comment: it worked, tnks. an upvote would be appreciated too